# Docker - PHP cURL by container name in the same network doesn't work

Tags: php, docker, curl, networking, containers

Long story short, I have dockerized the following (running on the same `docker network`)

- PHP app
- MySQL
- Spring Boot app

**[Link to docker-compose file](https://pastebin.com/4VUpcwbQ)**

#### Problem

Using PHP cURL by providing the `container name` doesn't work, but it works if I use the IPv4 address instead.

**What works**: `http://172.19.0.3:8080/api/test/` (IPv4 from the `docker network`)

**What doesn't**:

- `http://spring:8080/api/test/`
- `http://spring/api/test/`
- `spring:8080/api/test/`
- `spring/api/test/`

#### Expected

To work by using the `container name`

#### Made sure...

- They are running on the same `docker network`
- I spelled correctly the `container name` in the curl
- I provided the correct `port`

#### cURL code sample

```
$curl = curl_init("http://spring_api:8080/api/test/");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: application/json'
));

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
curl_close($curl);

return $response;
```

Comment: How did you start the containers? If you started them separately with docker run commands then they can't discover each other by names even if they are on the same network. Start them all with docker-compose and then you will be able to access them by name from within the docker network.

Comment: @Mihai I started them with docker-compose on the same file too

Comment: then make sure you start clean. Also can you post the docker-compose.yml, there might be an issue there.

Comment: Hi Jouo, try to use create a dedicated docker network for your containers and try it in that dedicated docker network. `docker network create myNetwork` and start your container with `docker run --network myNetwork myImage`

Comment: @Mihai Added the link to the docker-compose file

Comment: @ckaserer I'm doing that too, using it as an external network in my docker-compose file

Comment: Your setup looks good. Make sure to run `docker-compose down` since that will clean your environment. Then you can start the services with `docker-compose up` again. In the cURL example you give there is `http://spring_api:8080/api/test/`. If that is not a typo, then you have to make sure you replace spring_api with spring (the name of the service). There is no need to define the network, or to map ports for the Spring service. Keep your setup minimal ;)

Comment: @Mihai it is a typo on my post, I do am using the correct container name on my computer and I'm using the down command, I will just setup a static IPv4 since I ran out of ideas, tyvm for the help tho :D

Comment: You need to include the `docker-compose.yml` file _in the question_, not behind a link.  You also need to include the actual error you're getting and not just "doesn't work".  (A DNS error, a "connection refused" error, and an HTTP 404 are very different things.)

Comment: @DavidMaze it's because it just doesn't work, there's no actual error message, the function curl_error on PHP is not returning anything at all, I have three containers running on that network, PHP is able to connect to MySQL by using the container name, but not to the Spring container, at this point I'm sure the problem is not Docker related, but PHP related... somewhere